# && / || operator strangeness in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So, I was working on a project of mine, when I came across a problem like this:

```
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var three = 7;
if (one === 1 || two === 2 && three === 3) {
    console.log("ok"); // prints out ok
}
```

I'm pretty confused with this since I don't think it should print out "ok". I thought that since the condition after the && operator was false, it shouldn't run, but I'm evidently wrong. Can anyone clarify why it's working?

Comment: Operator precedence is `&&` over `||`, not just left-to-right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, operators are not just evaluated left-to-right, certain operators [have more precedence than others](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Those with higher precedence (in this case, the `&&` operator of precedence 13) will be evaluated before others (`||`, precedence 14).

---

For your particular case, you need to group your conditionals in order to achieve the functionality you want:

```
if ((one === 1 || two === 2) && three === 3) {
    console.log("ok"); // prints out ok
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDJ8z/)